# iTMSTransporter -vendor_id option not working

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, itmstransporter

I'm trying to lookup iTunes Connect metadata using iTMSTransporter. If I use the -apple_id option, everything works fine:

```
iTMSTransporter -m lookupMetadata -destination ~/Desktop/ -u my_email@gmail.com -apple_id 123456
```

However, if I use the -vendor_id option is fails with the following output:

```
[2017-03-15 20:21:31 PDT] iTMSTransporter -m lookupMetadata -destination ~/Desktop/ -u my_email@gmail.com -vendor_id MY_APP_SKU
[2017-03-15 20:21:31 PDT] <main> DBG-X: Apple's web service operation return value:
[2017-03-15 20:21:31 PDT] <main> DBG-X:   parameter ErrorMessage = No suitable application records were found. Verify your bundle identifier 'null' is correct. (1190)
[2017-03-15 20:21:31 PDT] <main> DBG-X:   parameter Errors = [No suitable application records were found. Verify your bundle identifier 'null' is correct. (1190)]
[2017-03-15 20:21:31 PDT] <main> DBG-X:   parameter ErrorCode = 1190
[2017-03-15 20:21:31 PDT] <main> DBG-X:   parameter Success = false
```

Has anything changed with Apple, iTunesConnect or iTMSTransporter? Before today, the -vendor_id option has always worked and I have double checked that all my values are correct.

Comment: Similar post on Apple Developer Forums: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/74293

Comment: I can only assume that they are changing / working on iTMSTransporter. I'm experiencing the same problems, but there's nothing to see in the Rev History: https://help.apple.com/itc/transporteruserguide/#/apdA1aded1d2 (Need to be logged into iTC, I think)

Comment: still not solved :(

Comment: Seems fixed now.